# Coordinate system broadcast by TxDOT NTRIP provider

Tags: coordinate-system, nad83, agisoft-photoscan

I am processing images in Agisoft Metashape. Images were collected in the Corpus Christi, TX area using TxDOT NTRIP Provider (RTN). In Agisoft Metashape, on the 'Reference Settings', I need to specify the 'Coordinate System' and the 'Camera reference'. These are some of the options available:

- NAD83(2011)/Texas South (EPSG:6585)
- NAD83(2011) (EPSG:6318)
- NAD83(2011) / Texas South Central (EPSG::6587)
- NAD83(2011) / Texas South (ftUS) (EPSG::6586)

I found this about the local station:
[image]

I was wondering which one is the most accurate to select.

Example of image coordinates:
Latitude: 27.782485
Longitude: -97.560364
Altitude: 15.02

Comment: Please add an example of the coordinates that you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XYZ coordinates are 3D Cartesian AKA geocentric coordinates. The output coordinates you have are in decimal degrees so they're on geographic 2D, NAD83(2011), not projected at all.